# Implementing facebook login with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, facebook, vue.js

I am implementing Facebook login in my Vue (nuxt) app with NodeJS backend.

I am able to receive my auth code, but am unable to get the access token using that. It keeps returning me the following error:

```
data: {
    error: {
      message: 'Missing redirect_uri parameter.',
      type: 'OAuthException',
      code: 191,
      fbtrace_id: 'AEzwwqCBEvvkq9mDQPrvc-7'
    }
  }
```

This is the code I have:

My page containing the facebook login button:

```
facebookLoginUrl () {
      const stringifiedParams = queryString.stringify({
        client_id: process.env.facebook_app_id,
        redirect_uri: process.env.base_url + this.$findPath('/authenticatie/facebook'),
        scope: ['public_profile', 'email', 'user_birthday', 'user_location', 'user_hometown'].join(','), // comma seperated string
        response_type: 'code',
        auth_type: 'rerequest',
        display: 'popup',
      })
      return `https://www.facebook.com/v4.0/dialog/oauth?${stringifiedParams}`
    }
```

The page where my redirect_uri is going to only contains the following in the created hook:

```
created () {
    let facebookAuthCode = this.$route.query.code
    let redirectUri = process.env.base_url + this.$findPath('/authenticatie/facebook')

    if (facebookAuthCode) {
      this.$getFromBackend('/getFacebookAccessTokenFromCode', { authCode: facebookAuthCode, redirectUri })
    }
  }
```

and finally my backend code does this:

```
axios.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/oauth/access_token', {
    client_id: process.env.facebook_app_id,
    client_secret: process.env.facebook_app_secret,
    redirect_uri: encodeURIComponent(redirectUri),
    code: encodeURIComponent(authCode),
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response)
    })
```

And it throws me the error mentioned above.

I can see in the error.response.config object the following:

```
config: {
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/oauth/access_token',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.2'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    client_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    client_secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/nl-be/authenticatie/facebook',
    code: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    data: undefined
  },
```

So the redirect_uri is set, whats going on?

UPDATE: I changed the axios code according to @CBroe answer:

```
axios.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/oauth/access_token', qs.stringify({
    client_id: process.env.facebook_app_id,
    client_secret: process.env.facebook_app_secret,
    redirect_uri: encodeURIComponent(redirectUri),
    code: encodeURIComponent(authCode),
  }), {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response)
    })
```

But i am getting the exact same error.

Comment: `axios.get` serializes data objects as JSON by default, but the API wants `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, according to docs. Try https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Comment: did you configure the redirect_uri on facebook?

Comment: @CBroe i changed the code to contain what you asked but i'm still getting the same error. Am I doing this correct?

Comment: @HarshSrivastava Aren't localhost url's always valid by default? It does not let me save a localhost URL regardless, it just immediately removes it upon saving the changes.
It's saying "http://localhost redirects are automatically allowed while in development mode only and do not need to be added here."

Comment: Try and make the request against a script of your own, or a public service endpoint like https://postman-echo.com/, and check if the debug output of that shows all parameters like it should.